# Why does my spreadsheet script throw a TypeError when I call getTime()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a small function using the Google Apps Script editor that checks that an event date in a spreadsheet is within 12 hours of the current date to send me a morning email notification. The for loop below loops through the dates column in my spreadsheet to find the current date (entered in the spreadsheet formatted as a date expressed as MM/DD/YYYY). I can't figure out why `schedule[i][0].getTime()` is giving me the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot find function getTime in object .`

Here's the function:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Schedule"); // get sheet
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow(); // find length of sheet
  var schedule = spreadsheet.getRange(6, 1, lastRow, 5).getValues(); // this an array with dates and info on events (first column has dates)
  var now = new Date().getTime(); // get today's date in ms
  var MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12 // get number of milliseconds in 12 hours
  for (var i=0; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var eventDate = schedule[i][0].getTime()
    if (now - eventDate < MILLIS && now > eventDate) {
        ...send email...
      };
  };
};
```

I've checked to make sure that the `schedule[i][0]` object is a valid date (e.g. `myvar instanceof Date`, debugger, format in google sheet, etc.), and everything indicates that it is. Yet, any method I've tried that nests the `if` clause in a function or calls `getTime()` more than once in the if statement causes a `TypeError`.

What am I doing wrong that is causing this error? How can I edit my code so that the condition in my `if` statement only runs if the difference between `now` and the date in `schedule[i][0]` is less than 12 hours?

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UvDV6pRw1fkEtu1eW7YDVUWww3Nho5qBSCV124V1gd8/edit?usp=sharing) to a spreadsheet showing how the data is formatted.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I edited the question to match the "minimal reproducible example" format. The problem is with the for loop, which doesn't account for the header. Thanks to tehhowch for the fix.

Comment: What is `limit`

Comment: Good catch! lastRow used to be called limit, and I didn't change it in the for loop. Fixed.

Comment: Quote the exact script and the line that causes the error. See [mcve]. Don't use `...` like `if( ... && now > schedule[i][0].getTime())`. If you're going to provide the sheet with script, make sure the problem is reproducible in the provided spreadsheet.

Comment: Incorrect ending condition in your `for` loop. Arrays are 0-base indexed. Thus when `i` is equal to `lastRow`, the array access returns `undefined` and you cannot call methods on that value (since `undedined` has no methods`). It's actually sooner than that, since you don't account for header row offset in the number of rows you query.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I can also edit the question so that it has the right format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per tehhowch, the problem is that my `for` loop did not account for the header rows in my spreadsheet or that an array is 0-indexed.

Removing the empty rows in the array and giving the right limit in the for loop fixed the problem:

```
...
function sendEmail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Schedule"); // get active sheet
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow(); // find length of sheet
  var schedule = spreadsheet.getRange(6, 1, lastRow - 5, 5).getValues(); // get values from first column of dates 
  var now = new Date().valueOf(); // get today's date
  var MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12 // get number of ms in 12 hours
  for (var i=0; i <= schedule.length - 1; i++) { 
    var eventDate = schedule[i][0].getTime()
    if (now - eventDate < MILLIS && now > eventDate) { 
      ...send email...
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on your data.

Using your data and a few minor tweaks to the code.  I also used valueOf() instead of getTime() ...it's some thing I prefer using.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet177");
  var schedule = sh.getRange(6, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); // this an array with dates and info on events (first column has dates)
  var halfday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12;
  var idxA=[];
  for (var i=0;i<schedule.length;i++) {
    var now=new Date().valueOf();
    var sked=new Date(schedule[i][0]).valueOf();
    var diff=now-sked;
    if ((diff<halfday) && (now>sked)) {
      idxA.push(i);//I am just collecting the indexes of the var schedule that are within 12 hours of now.
      //send email
    }
  }
  Logger.log(idxA);
}
```

Comment: No need! The code as written works since `schedule[i][0]` is a date. The problem is that when I try to add a second instance of `schedule[i][0].getTime()` with the following if statement: `if (now.getTime() - schedule[i][0].getTime() < MILLIS && now.getTime() > schedule[i][0].getTime())`, I get the TypeError.

Comment: Can you share some of your data? Or a like to the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Here's a link, thanks! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UvDV6pRw1fkEtu1eW7YDVUWww3Nho5qBSCV124V1gd8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, declaring the value of `now` initially is more concise. I added that above!